# Wordpress Custom Post Types And Custom Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress-theming

For a test i have been given following topics.

1)Taxonomies

2)Custom Post Types

3)Data extraction from Database for use in posts and plugins

**so far i have learnt**

```
register_post_type()

register_taxanomy()

wpdb class
```

**So My Question Is**

1)What other topics/functions do i need to learn.Can somebody provide me link to resorces where i can learn aditional topics other than offical docs.

2)If i have to create a custom post type and add custom taxonomy to it can you somebody give me a sketch of how this can be done i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this type of question doesn't work well on Stack Overflow, and it may get closed. The best bet is probably to Google around for an introductory article

Comment: Yes!That is what i was afraid of.thanks